# Using full stops in figure name to replace spaces: error (confusion of file extension)

Tags: floats, errors, auxiliary-files

I am not sure this has been asked before, but I couldn't find it and I am hoping to get a solution or at least a good explanation of why this is a bad idea. (there are questions about using underscore or spaces, but as far as I can tell nothing about full stops).

I started using full stops to replace spaces in file names but LaTeX does not seem to accept this. For example, when I name the figure `figSE.pdf` the code compiles fine, but if I name it instead `fig.SE.pdf` I get the error message

> ERROR: LaTeX Error: Unknown graphics extension: .SE.pdf.

I know I can just rename the file, but I quite like my new system and if there is a way to make LaTeX accept it I would prefer (and I don't want to use hyphens nor underscores).

Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{fig.SE.pdf}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

And an example of a figure can be found here: http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/1885087/fig.SE.pdf

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First things first:
You don't have to include any graphicx extension.

```
\includegraphics{figSE}
```

works, too.

Now, LaTeX uses the first period to find out what extension you're using, but you can hide that:

```
\includegraphics{{fig.SE}.pdf}
```

or even:

```
\includegraphics{{{fig.SE}}}
```

Comment: I should have known this. I feel embarrassed now.

Comment: @Vivi Ah, no problem. LaTeX 101: If something fails, add a pair of braces. :) By the way, there is a `1` included in your graphic.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "there is a 1 included in your graphic"

Comment: @Vivi In your `fig.SE.pdf` is the digit “1” embedded in the graph (at around (1977 | –0.02)).

Comment: I hadn't seen that! Thanks! This figure was generated by tikzDevice in R, and either the code came with the 1 or I accidentally put it there when handling the file. In any case, I plan on getting a much better version, probably by writing the tikz file myself, at a later stage. This is more like a place holder at the moment.

Answer (score 7):

Use braces like `\includegraphics{{fig.SE}.pdf}`. This method works even if you have space like `\includegraphics{{fig SE}.pdf}`.

Another way of including graphics files with spaces is to use the package `grffile`. Simply put

```
\usepackage[space]{grffile}
```

in your preamble.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[space]{grffile}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{fig SE.pdf}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great! Your answer has some very useful points, but since Qrrbrbirlbel answered it first I am accepting his answer (as both answer my question).

Answer (score 3):

Package `grffile` adds support for multiple dots to graphics file names:

```
\usepackage{grffile}
```